# Make IWYU analyze included headers, not just main program

Tags: c++, cmake, iwyu

I have a project which I compile with

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_CXX_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE="iwyu"
make
```

The problem is that `iwyu` seems to be only looking at the `*.cpp` files being compiled and not at headers included from the `cpp` itself.
What option you I pass to `iwyu` to force to analyze included headers.
Of course I wouldn't be interested in reports of system headers (`-isystem`) but I am interested in headers that belong to the same project.

I tried with the option `--check_also=*.hpp` but I get the message `error: unsupported option '--check_also=hpp'`.

The versions I am using are:

`iwyu --version include-what-you-use 0.17 based on Ubuntu clang version 13.0.1-2ubuntu2`

`apt-get --version     apt 2.4.7 (amd64)`

---

I realized that I have to put `-Xiwyu` in front any option.
So, I have to do `-Xiwyu --check_also=*.hpp` but now I get this error:

```
Error running 'iwyu': iwyu: /usr/lib/llvm-11/include/clang/AST/Decl.h:251: llvm::StringRef clang::NamedDecl::getName() const: Assertion `Name.isIdentifier() && "Name is not a simple identifier"' failed.
```

which makes me think that this doesn't support patterns but individual files.

So, it seems that the use through cmake is not very useful for this case and it is better to check the whole project using:

```
find ./include -name '*.hpp' -exec iwyu -Xiwyu --cxx17ns -Xiwyu --quoted_includes_first -std=c++17 {} \;
```

Comment: Also found this related conversation: https://github.com/include-what-you-use/include-what-you-use/issues/268

Comment: If that github discussion provides you the information to solve your problem, then write up an answer. If not, edit your question to summarize its points and explain what you still need. Note: If you decide you want to just participate in the github discussion instead of pursuing an answer here, delete this question.

Comment: @rainbow.gekota, it doesn't. I can use `--check_also=*.hpp` but then I get a lot of errors (described in the question). So I wonder if I am doing something wrong.